# Function.prototype.bind.apply meaning not understood

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was looking at injector code of angular and could not understand this line

```
Function.prototype.bind.apply(ctor, args)
```

of code. Why would we call apply for bind? isn't it like calling apply for apply?

I read it on some question that it can be used to call a function of arbitrary arguments, but that can be done with `arguments` object,  right?

Can some one clear this?

Actual angular code:

```
 function instantiate(Type, locals, serviceName) {
      // Check if Type is annotated and use just the given function at n-1 as parameter
      // e.g. someModule.factory('greeter', ['$window', function(renamed$window) {}]);
      var ctor = (isArray(Type) ? Type[Type.length - 1] : Type);
      var args = injectionArgs(Type, locals, serviceName);
      // Empty object at position 0 is ignored for invocation with `new`, but required.
      args.unshift(null);
      return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(ctor, args))();
    }
```

Comment: args is probably an array.

Comment: Yeah, apply for arrays and call for arguments in order to assign ctor as  this

Answer (score 5):

Skip the `Function.prototype.bind.apply`

First we will see [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

> The apply() method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided as an `array` (or an array-like object).

### Syntax

```
fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
```

---

So with the above syntax it is clearly understood that `apply` method calls the given function with first argument as `this` and second argument as `Array`

So lets breakdown into steps

- [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) will return a new function with pre-bound `this` value. ( and it is introduced in ES5 ).
- `apply` method invokes a function with given two parameters as below.

  1. First parameter is `this`
  2. Second parameter is Array / Array like object
- So in our case we are passing `ctor` as `this` and `args` as Array / Array like object to `apply` method.

Here comes the final version `return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(ctor, args))();`

- We can break down the above line into two lines so that it will be easily readable.

  1. `var func = Function.prototype.bind.apply(ctor, args)`;
  2. 'return new func();`

And the above code is used by `injector` to get the instance of `service` in angular.

By definition an Angular service will return the `new'ed` function so the above code is doing the same.

> Services return the object through a function constructor. That is why you can use the keyword ‘this’ inside the Service.

```
function instantiate(Type, locals, serviceName) {
      // Check if Type is annotated and use just the given function at n-1 as parameter
      // e.g. someModule.factory('greeter', ['$window', function(renamed$window) {}]);
      var ctor = (isArray(Type) ? Type[Type.length - 1] : Type);
      var args = injectionArgs(Type, locals, serviceName);
      // Empty object at position 0 is ignored for invocation with `new`, but required.
      args.unshift(null);
      return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(ctor, args))();
    }
```

Comment: Sure, the syntax is understandable but what's the purpose of the code? What does it do?

Comment: @AndrewLi I guess, I've answered whatever OP is asked.

Comment: and what does bind does?

Comment: ok I want to ask what is the purpose?

Comment: @anurag bind will return a new function with pre-bounded `this'

Comment: @anurag Ask your question clearly. If you want line by line explanation Ask for the same or if you want what the function is doing ask for it?
Be specific on your question.